# Select data from ms sql with where cluase

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select

I have a ms MSSQL which i can run

```
 SELECT * FROM dbo.Alrams
```

and the result is like below:

[image]

But when i am trying to select using Where clause i get below errors.

[image]

[image]

do you have any suggestions?

**UPDATE:**
All my columns are text

Comment: `SELECT * FROM dbo.Alrams WHERE AlarmId='25888'` remove bracket as well as double quotes

Comment: i got Operand type clash: text is incompatible with smallint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use single quotes for string literals. Double quotes is used for identifiers that's why `25888` is considered as column name.

When you pass `25888` without single quotes, it will be treated as integer type. Integer cannot be compared with `text`

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Alrams WHERE AlarmId like '25888'
```

Stop using `Text`, use `varchar` instead `text` can be removed in future versions

Comment: i got The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.

Comment: @SinaNouri - Use `Like` operator .. Updated check now

Comment: what do you suggest for $sql="SELECT * FROM dbo.Alarms WHERE AlarmID in ('6954','6042','5664','4788','5678','4844','6056','5042','6302','13122','4956','6044','6224','5666','4790','4886','5680','5044','6058','6304','13124','4958','6226','4792','4888','5046','13126','6440','5998','5708','3932','65035','10714','5700','10774','13070','25622')";

Comment: @SinaNouri Put the values in a temp table and join the temp table with `dbo.Alrams` using `like` operator

Comment: i changed columns to varchar and all the problems made by text is resolved now.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, don'use double quote to mark text.  IN MSSQL single quote is delimiter for text .

Eg. `SELECT * FROM YOURTABLE WHERE COLUMN = 'abcd';`